# how to execute LIKE query in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, select, sqlalchemy

I am using `sqlalchemy` to fetch data from tables.
Right now fetching all records from a table called `audit_trail_table` is working as expected.

```
select_stmt = select([self.audit_trail_table]).where(self.audit_trail_table.c.id == int(id))
row = conn.execute(select_stmt).fetchone()
```

Now I wish to execute `LIKE` queries on multiple columns as follows:

```
filter_query = #(some value which will work as a filter_query while fetching )records
filter_stmt = select([self.audit_trail_table]).where(self.audit_trail_table.c.first_name like '%' + filter_query + '%' or self.audit_trail_table.c.last_name like '%')
```

But it gives an error at LIKE. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`like`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.like) operator:

```
select([self.audit_trail_table]).where(
    self.audit_trail_table.c.first_name.like('%' + filter_query + '%') or 
    self.audit_trail_table.c.last_name.like('%abc%')
)
```

Comment: It is working for a single `like()`. But I am getting an error when I combine two `like()` functions with `or` as : `TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined`

Comment: u have to use OR operator from django instead of OR operator from python

Comment: Yes. I have used `or_()` from sqlalchemy instead. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: You can also use [`contains`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.contains) in place of `like`

Comment: @RedBaron That should be an answer, not hidden in the comments section!