# Case-insensitive exact match with SQLAlchemy

Tags: database, performance, sqlalchemy, string-comparison

How can I ensure that the `=` operator is always rendered case-insensitive? Are comparisions with the `LOWER` or the `UPPER` functions the best bet for performance? `ILIKE` seems to be very slow.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16573095/5320906).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you need only case-insensitivity use **upper** or **lower** since **like** is not only about case-insensitivity

example of **lower**:

```py
my_string = 'BarFoo'
session.query(Foo).filter(func.lower(Foo.bar) == my_string.lower()).all()
```

see some more info on **like** here [how to execute LIKE query in sqlalchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822371/how-to-execute-like-query-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: Imported as `from sqlalchemy import func`

Comment: For flask-sqlalchemy do we have such func ?
I found it in '''db.func'''

Answer (score 2):

For case-insensitive comparisons, you can subclass `Comparator`.

> [Building Custom Comparators](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#building-custom-comparators)

The example class below allows case-insensitive comparisons on the attribute named `word_insensitive`:

```py
    from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import Comparator, hybrid_property
    from sqlalchemy import func, Column, Integer, String
    from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

    Base = declarative_base()

    class CaseInsensitiveComparator(Comparator):
        def __eq__(self, other):
            return func.lower(self.__clause_element__()) == func.lower(other)

    class SearchWord(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'searchword'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        word = Column(String(255), nullable=False)

        @hybrid_property
        def word_insensitive(self):
            return self.word.lower()

        @word_insensitive.comparator
        def word_insensitive(cls):
            return CaseInsensitiveComparator(cls.word)
```

Above, SQL expressions against `word_insensitive` will apply the `LOWER()` SQL function to both sides:

```py
    >>> print Session().query(SearchWord).filter_by(word_insensitive="Trucks")
    SELECT searchword.id AS searchword_id, searchword.word AS searchword_word FROM searchword
    WHERE lower(searchword.word) = lower(:lower_1)
```

The `CaseInsensitiveComparator` above implements part of the `ColumnOperators` interface. A “coercion” operation like lowercasing can be applied to all comparison operations (i.e. `eq`, `lt`, `gt`, etc.) using `Operators.operate()`:

```py
    class CaseInsensitiveComparator(Comparator):
        def operate(self, op, other):
            return op(func.lower(self.__clause_element__()), func.lower(other))
```